# Is it ok to store my Android app keystore password in a text file on my disk?

Tags: android, key-management, key, code-signing

I am reading on how to sign and publish my flutter app on android.

When reading through the [official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android), they suggest to make a configuration file where I put my password to the keystore in plain text. I feel like that is a bad idea, but maybe I am missing something. The Keystore is used to sign my app for publishing on the play store. If someone gains control of the keystore, they could upload new versions of my app to the playstore. Should I not want to keep the password to this keystore secure? I don't intend to commit this file to git or anything, but I could imagine someone making that mistake as well.

Comment: Are you not using [Google Play App Signing](https://play.google.com/console/about/keymanagement)?

Comment: Google Play App signing still requires a upload keystore.